# Migration of Java Application from 1.5 to 1.8

Tags: java, performance, java-8, version, java-5

We are working in the project of migrating a application(built in java 5)
to java 8 for better performance,

But , we are not sure that
1. upgrade an environment or
2.Build that complete app in java 8 from scratch,

and how it will improve the performance !

And we know that, There will be some Deprecated API's from version to version.
so, while upgrading is it possible to get error or miss some functionality ?

How can We rectify that?

Please comment your suggestions !

Comment: It depends upon, what performance bottlenecks you are facing which cannot be handled by Java 5, what makes you think Java 8 can be the messiah! Also its hard to comment on such a broad topic, your codebase will tell you if you will get any errors, without code we can only be guessing. Voting to close this question as its too broad and primarily opinion based.

Comment: What kind of Java application and how  many classes, frameworks, libraries, databases, etc., I'd like to know.

Comment: Trying to launch the existing application in a newer JRE or trying to compile the application with a newer compiler/language level takes less time than writing a question on Stackoverflow and waiting for responses…

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Java has full backward compatability, So

1. If you just change java version then it will not have any errors as java8 is fully compatible with previous java versions.
2. If you want to improve performance using java8, Then you have to read java8 release notes to know where you can get faster alternative of current code and then you can only re-wright that functionality only

Answer (score -1):

firstly you can always migrate to newer version of java as java is backward compatible. Also, you are right, few API's might have been deprecated but you always have the new options of those which can be solved. 
My suggestion would be, if you don't have huge code or a bulky API, re-write the same in new version as u might utilize benefits of functional programming.

Comment: What are the benefits of 'Functional Programming' ?